# Is CA2007 relevant to a .NET Core application?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, fxcop

When I run FxCop on my project, I get a large number of warnings with the ID of CA2007. This ID is missing from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/code-analysis-warnings-for-managed-code-by-checkid?view=vs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2017) (it just skips from CA2006 to CA2100), but the message I get is:

> Do not directly await a Task without calling ConfigureAwait

I was under the impression that .NET Core didn't use synchronisation contexts and that this meant I didn't need to use `.ConfigureAwait(bool)`. When I try and Google it though, I can now only find mentions of ASP.NET Core (e.g. [this blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html)).

Given that I can't find anything authoritative, I'm beginning to wonder whether I've mistaken an ASP.NET Core change for one that applies more generally to all of .NET Core.

Can anyone give me a definitive answer?

Should I need to go through my app and apply a liberal sprinkling of `ConfigureAwait`? Or should I just disable CA2007 in my FxCop ruleset?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes in some situations. If your code is ever used as a library or someone introduces a SynchronizationContext. refer to this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/#ive-heard-configureawaitfalse-is-no-longer-necessary-in-net-core-true). https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/#ive-heard-configureawaitfalse-is-no-longer-necessary-in-net-core-true